# How to marshal a Java Object from SOAP response to xml string with no @XmlRootElement?

Tags: java, xml, soap, jaxb, marshalling

I have a Java object that's returned from a SOAP request, and all I want to do is marshal it to an XML string.

The problem is the class definition of this object is unavailable to me to edit as it's compiled source and it has no @XmlRootElement annotation, so it fails when I try to marshal it the conventional way with a JAXBElement and Marshaller.

Even when I use a QName like this:

```
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Car.class);
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

        // format the XML output
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        QName qName = new QName("info.source4code.jaxb.model", "car");
        JAXBElement<Car> root = new JAXBElement<Car>(qName, Car.class, car);

        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(root, stringWriter);
```

I get an exception:

```
javax.xml.bind.MarshalException - with linked exception: [javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class org.com.RetrieveDetailsResponse nor any of its super class is known to this context.]
```

The class is defined like:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "retrieveDetailsResponse", propOrder = {
    "detailsList"
})
public class RetrieveDetailsResponse {
```

All I want to do is turn this response into XML text which seems simple enough but is driving me crazy, please help.

---

Edit: I tried the answer from the similar question posted below but it does not fix my problem.

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693552/java-code-to-xml-xsd-without-using-annotation

Comment: As I mentioned, using the QName did not work for me. Still "[javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: org.com.RetrieveDetailsResponse is not known to this context]"

Comment: What is Car.class? You should do `JAXBContext.newInstance(RetrieveDetailsResponse.class)`

Comment: Turns out it does fix my problem. Please post an answer and I'll accept it. thanks

Comment: If the question I linked to answers your question, you should probably close as duplicate